# Parcelable android add empty char to the String field value

Tags: android, serialization, parcelable

I need to implement some mechanism to pass data between Activities. First, I made my classes Serializable and everything worked fine. Then I had a task to pass ArrayList of my custom objects. Serializable do not maintain such feature in android and I decided to implement Parcelable. But when I create one object of my class, it adds empry char to `name` field of the object. Somebody faced with similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my isuue. Problem was that order of the fields in the class constructor and writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) and readFromParcel(Parcel in) do not match. So the order is important !.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to serialize whole classes? You can simply put various objects (ArrayList as well) into [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html), pass it to the other activities and then use it to recreate your classes.